# Rails update form field value based on collection_select value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I am relatively new to Rails and I have been searching the forums for what seems like forever and I have not found a solution to my problem. It is probably just due to my inexperience as a developer but I would appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

I am building an application that has a rounds model and each round has many investors (which is a separate model). In addition, there is also a Stock model that has various data about the type of stock that the investor is purchasing. All necessary relationships between the models have been established.

When I create a new investor, I am trying to auto-fill the form based on the type of stock that has been selected. Here is the form:

```
//app/views/investors/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(@investor) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :security_name %>
  <%= f.collection_select :stock_type, Stock.all, :id, :security_name, prompt: true, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :share_price %>
  <%= f.number_field :share_price, :readonly => true, class: 'form-control'%>

  <%= f.submit "Add Investor", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The first field in the form is a dropdown box that allows the user to select the type of stock that the investor buys. This is functioning properly.

What I have not been able to figure out (and what I need help with) is how to  automatically set the value of the number_field to be the share price of the selected stock type. I know that it requires some form of Javascript but everything that I have tried has not produced a functional output.

Part of the issue that I have been having is that when I read responses to other people's questions, I am not entirely sure where to place the code that has been suggested - so this information would also be helpful.

Using Rails version 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the logic for share_price is simple. I would just use a data field to add that value to all the  tags of the select.

`options_for_select([["GOOGLE", "1", {data: {price: "25.6"}}], ["Apple", "2", , {data: {price: "25.6"}}], ...])`

Then in a javascript snipet above your form or in a proper investor.js.coffee file.

`$("#investor_stock_type").change () ->
  $("#investor_share_price").value = $(this).data("price")`

Potential syntax errors aside. This should get you close to what you want.